# Remove remotely logged in users?

Tags: windows-7, remote-access

How can I prevent users (who have remotely logged before) from logging into the computer, without changing the password?

*Answered by Journeyman and William*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Go to system properties, go to remote, then hit the <kbd>Select Remote Users...</kbd> button. Then select and remove the users in question. Admin users *always* have remote access rights so, if you need to prevent them from doing this, disable remote access completely

Comment: Glad to be of help, but.. did it work? If it did you may want to select this as the correct answer. That way people who come to this site in future will know it actually worked for you.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. But unfortunately I don't have the "privilege" to vote up this answer! (having just 6 rep' points!) *I've already given my feedback as 'useful'.

Answer (score 3):

If each user has their own account, you can right click `computer`, go to `Manage`, then, select `Local Users and Groups` > `Users`, double click their name and choose `Account is disabled`.

[image]

Comment: @CRoshanLG This will stop them logging in completely - ie locally aswell as remotely.

Comment: Yes HaydnWVN. Got to learn it by practical application of this method! (No harm done, by the way! Just created a new account again. :) )